# Centre image within html list with css

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile, html-lists

I have the following:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3cywz/12/)

and I wish for the images to be centred vertically for each item in the list. How can I do this?

```
<li>
   <img src="Scotland.jpg" />
   <h3>Scotland 4</h3>
   <p>P1</p>
   <p>P2</p>
   <p>P3</p>
   <p>P4</p>
   <p>P5</p>
   <p>P6</p>
   <p>P7</p>
   <p>P8</p> 
</li>
```

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: @Itay Yeah, I tried setting vertical-align: middle; for .ui-li-thumb

Comment: @Baz View my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/3cywz/16/0)

Add these CSS blocks:

```
li {
    position: relative;
}
li img {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

P.S - Notice that these CSS selectors are way too general, so use a container class or ID to make them more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3cywz/20/)

```
img {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin:auto;
}
```